# Understanding callback.call function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, callback, call

Please go through the below code.
I am not able to exactly what's calllback.call is doing.

Also, I am not able to know what is the difference between this and this[i] and how if(callback.call(this, this[i])) is evaluated to true or false.

```
Array.prototype.each = function(callback) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < this.length) {
    callback.call(this, this[i]);
    i++;
  }
  return this;
};

Array.prototype.map = function(callback) {
var i = this.length;
var found = []
while (i--) {
  if(callback.call(this, this[i])) {
    found.push(this[i]);
  }
}
return found;
};
```

The functions are called below:

```
Array.each(function(value){
...
})

Array.map(function(value){
...
})
```

Comment: In both cases `each` and `map` is assigned a function.

Comment: Wouldn't you call the function like `[1,2,3].each(function(){ /* do something */})` ?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to exactly what's calllback.call is doing.

[Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) lets you invoke a function with an explicit value for `this`

```
callback.call(this, this[i]);
```

is the same as

```
callback(this[i])
```

except that inside the callback the value of `this` is the set to be the same as it was in the current context.

---

> Also am not able to know what is the difference between this and this[i].

In this context, `this` is the current array. So `this` means the whole array, `this[i]` gets the i'th element of the array.

---

The `.each` function you have will loop through an array and call a function for each of them. This is similar to javascript's built in [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

The `.map` is named as though it were a polyfill for [Array.protoype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but is actually doing a .filter operation. Strange.

Comment: Can i know how if(callback.call(this, this[i])) is evaluated to true or false

Comment: What function are you passing in as the callback? It's all going to be down to what that function returns.